# Access to DataGrid inside other DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, datagrid

i have two `DataGrid` `Concour` and `Epruve` i want to make `Epreuve` Shows when a row from `Concour` is selected .. my problem is how to get access to the `DataGrid` `Epreuve` To Fill it from `MySQL`.

This is what i tried

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Concours" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" SelectionChanged="Concour_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="288,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="345" Width="652">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid x:Name="Epreuve" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Désignation" Binding="{Binding Designation}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Coefficient" Binding="{Binding Coef}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

**CS**

```
private void Concour_SelectionChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the First Cell Value
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ((DataView)Concours.ItemsSource).ToTable();
        List<String> L = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            L.Add((String)row[0]);
        }
        int row_number = Concours.SelectedIndex;
        //Connect To DataBase (gestion_concour)
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.Server = "127.0.0.1";
        builder.UserID = "root";
        builder.Password = "root";
        builder.Database = "gestion_concour";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ToString());
        connection.Open();
        //Fill Epreuve 
        String q = "SELECT * FROM gestion_Concour.concour WHERE Code = @Code";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, connection);
        cmd.CommandText = q;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", L[row_number]);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MySqlDataAdapter DA = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable("Epreuve");
        DA.Fill(DT);
        Epreuve.ItemSource = DT.DefaultView;
        DA.Update(DT);
        connection.Close();
    }
```

and i got this ERROR

> The name 'Epreuve' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I think i have to do somthing Like ItemsSource = "{Binding Epreuve}" that didn't work .. but i think some modificaion and it will

Answer (score 1):

i changed the `Concour_SelectionChnged` and use `Concour_LoadRowDetails`

**CS**

```
public void Concour_LoadRowDetails (object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
    {
        Eprv = e.DetailsElement.FindName("Epreuve") as DataGrid;
        MessageBox.Show("Epreuve Loaded");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ((DataView)Concours.ItemsSource).ToTable();
        List<String> L = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            L.Add((String)row[0]);
        }
        int row_number = Concours.SelectedIndex;
        //Connect To DataBase (gestion_concour)
        MessageBox.Show(L[row_number]);
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.Server = "127.0.0.1";
        builder.UserID = "root";
        builder.Password = "root";
        builder.Database = "gestion_concour";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ToString());
        connection.Open();
        //Fill Epreuve 
        String q = "SELECT * FROM gestion_Concour.Epreuve WHERE Concour_Code = @Code";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, connection);
        cmd.CommandText = q;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", L[row_number]);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MySqlDataAdapter DA = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable DS = new DataTable();
        DA.Fill(DS);
        Eprv.ItemsSource = DS.DefaultView;
        DA.Update(DS);
        connection.Close();
    }
```